# On debugging...it says i have index out of range error on line hr[i] = h1. How to fix it?

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
hr = list()
freq = list()
i=0
k=0
handle = open(name)
for line in handle:
    if line.startswith('From'):
        h1 = line.split()[5].split(':')[0]
        if h1 not in hr:
            hr[i] = h1
            i=i+1

for j in range(hr):
     for line in handle:
        if line.startswith('From'):
            h2 = line.split()[5].split(':')[0]
            if hr[j] == h2:
                freq[j] = k+1

for l in range(hr): 
      print hr[l],freq[l]
```

Comment: I am confused by `for j in range(hr):` my Python 2.7 complains, as I expected, since `range()` does not accept a list as an argument

Comment: @pynchia yes sorry for that..it will be range(len(hr))

Answer (score 1):

You reference the first item in a list "h[0]" on a list with zero items.  Python does not implicitly append items.  Use this instead:

```
hr.append(h1)
```

Comment: yep..thanx that worked but now it says h2 = line.split()[5].split(':')[0] has list index out of range. I have to read from a file which contains log of emails from users...a typical line being : From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008 where i have to separate '09' from the line. Please help and also explain why this error occurs

Comment: I am no expert, but maybe you could use a regular expression, like: `match = re.search(r'^.*\d{2}:', st)` and (if there's a match) from there get the end position of the year you need to exclude: `ep = match.end()`  `newstring = inputstr[:ep-3]+inputstr[ep:]`

Comment: a much more elegant solution on one line: `newstring = re.sub(r'(?P<pref>^.*)(?P<year>\d{2}:)',r'\g<pref>:', inputstr)`

Comment: I suppose that you have a line that begins with "from" which does not have six substrings separated by whitespace?  You might wrap this statement in a try...except statement and handle the exception.